# Negative Binomial - pvalues for log vs pvalues for response scale?

Tags: p-value, negative-binomial-distribution, lsmeans

I am performing a negative binomial regression, with post-hoc tests using `emmeans`. I was wondering if I should perform & report the p-values done using the log scale or the response scale.

I am posting an example. In this case, there is not a big difference between approaches but, I am dealing with a scenario where the differences are clearer and more important.

```
library(emmeans)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1234)

df<-data.frame(v1=c(rnegbin(n=50,90,theta=10),
                    rnegbin(n=50,50,theta=10),
                    rnegbin(n=50,75,theta = 10)),
               v2=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50),rep("C",50)))
               

m1<-glm.nb(v1~v2,data=df)

emmeans::emmeans(specs=pairwise~v2,m1)
emmeans::emmeans(specs=pairwise~v2,m1,regrid="response")
```

**Edit:**
Changed the `theta` criteria in order to solve the issue raised by @GordonSmyth

Comment: The data example you have generated has different negative binomial dispersion parameters for different groups and therefore does not match the assumptions of the `glm.nb` or `emmeans` functions.

Comment: My preference with negative binomial glms is always to use likelihood ratio tests (LRTs), for example using the R anova() function, rather than Wald or least squares based tests. With LRTs there would be no need to choose the response scale.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GordonSmyth! But, using `anova` or LRT, how could I perform the pairwise comparisons?

Comment: Your `v2` vector has 300 elements but your `v1` vector has only 150 elements. Is that what you intended? R will automatically repeat your `v1` vector but your three groups will not be iid random samples.

Comment: @GordonSmyth thanks, corrected that too!

Comment: Given a choice between those two, I think the link scale is the better choice because that's the scale on which the model was fitted. Note you can specify type = "response" instead of regrid = "response" and then the tests are on the link scale and the estimates are displayed on the response scale. Also note that with the regrid fed scale, it's possible to get confidence intervals that go negative.

Answer (score 2):

My preference with negative binomial glms is always to use likelihood ratio tests (LRTs) using R anova's function rather than Wald or least squares based tests. With LRTs there is no need to choose the response scale. LRTs will be vastly better than other tests if one or more of the group means are close to zero.

Here is an example similar to yours.
First, generate the data:

```
> library(MASS)
> set.seed(1234)
> v1 <- rnbinom(150,mu=rep(c(90,50,75),c(50,50,50)),size=10)
> Group <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),c(50,50,50)))
```

Now define simplified factors in which pairs of groups are equated:

```
> GroupAeqB <- Group
> levels(GroupAeqB) <- c("AB","AB","C")
> GroupAeqC <- Group
> levels(GroupAeqC) <- c("AC","B","AC")
> GroupBeqC <- Group
> levels(GroupBeqC) <- c("A","BC","BC")
```

Now fit full and null glms.
We ensure that that all three glms are fitted with the same negative binomial dispersion, as estimated from the full model.

```
> library(MASS)
> fit <- glm.nb(v1 ~ Group)
> fit$theta
[1] 10.73855
> fitAeqB <- glm(v1 ~ GroupAeqB, family=negative.binomial(fit$theta))
> fitAeqC <- glm(v1 ~ GroupAeqC, family=negative.binomial(fit$theta))
> fitBeqC <- glm(v1 ~ GroupBeqC, family=negative.binomial(fit$theta))
```

Then conduct likelihood ratio tests:

```
> anova(fitAeqB,fit,test="Chi")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: v1 ~ GroupAeqB
Model 2: v1 ~ Group
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       148     239.45                          
2       147     152.40  1   87.052 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(fitAeqC,fit,test="Chi")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: v1 ~ GroupAeqC
Model 2: v1 ~ Group
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1       148     161.12                        
2       147     152.40  1   8.7145 0.003157 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(fitBeqC,fit,test="Chi")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: v1 ~ GroupBeqC
Model 2: v1 ~ Group
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       148     193.61                          
2       147     152.40  1   41.205 1.371e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The three pairwise p-values are 2.2e-16 (A vs B), 0.003157 (A vs C) and 1.371e-10 (B vc C).

R doesn't like to quote p-values lower than 2e-16. The exact A vs B p-value is actually a bit smaller:

```
> pchisq(87.052, df=1, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 1.057051e-20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In a scenario where I have an additional explanatory variable (let's call it v3), continuous, that can be considered as confounding. 2 questions come to mind:

1) By doing these models of pairs, using ~v2 + v3, wouldn't it be a problem that the v3 value will be different among the said models?

2) In that scenario, would you go for Anova type II?

Comment: In addition, I might be wrong but, isn't the LRT and Wald & Least Squared based tests hypotheses inherently different? As far as I understand it, LRT determines if the additional variable allows the model to explain more variation/being more informative, while Wald tests are focused in determining if the estimate is different from zero.

Comment: Having extra covariates or factors in the model causes no problems at all. The LRTs are automatically adjusted for any other covariates in the model. You could think of it as analogous to analysis of covariance, but it is just standard glm theory.

Comment: LRT and Wald tests are completely equivalent in the sense that both types of tests are used to test the same null and alternative hypotheses. The two types of tests are in fact asymptotically equivalent when the maximum likelihood estimators are very accurate but can be very different for small sample sizes or small counts or exact fits.

Comment: Thanks for all the information & corrections.

Another question - would you adjust these p-values for multiple comparisons, e.g. holm or bonferroni?

Comment: You could apply Holm's adjustment but, with only three comparisons, adjustment is not a critical issue.